# "Here is the following homework for today:”

Tags: phrase-usage

> Here is the following homework for today:
> #1 Spelling worksheet
> #2 Handwriting page3

I don’t think “Here is the following homework for today:” is not appropriate, but grammatically correct?

I thought the followings would be better.

> 1.Today’s homework:
> 2.Today’s homework is:
> 3.Today’s homework is as follows:
> 4.Here is today’s homework:
> 5.Followings are today's homework:

Can I change "today's homework" of all of the above (1~5) to "homework for today"?

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestions 1 through 4 are all better than the original. Your suggestion 5 would be alright as "The following is today's homework:".

The original doesn't work. The problem is that it is pointing to the homework in two different ways, that is, with "here" and with "following".
It should be either
Here is the homework for today.
or
The following is the homework for today.